# htaccess RewriteRule _route_=$1 https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, https, opencart

I have inherited support for an Opencart 1.5 site which needs to have SSL enabled.

I've edited the config.php files in / and admin/ and adding https:// to the URL is working in the browser and links are being generated with https

However, whatever method of an htaccess redirect I try seems to result in the site not loading.

The following is in the htaccess file and I suspect the problem is related to the last line here with *route* which I've not seen before.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any suggestions on how I can add https to this RewriteRule?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I've reposted the question over at Webmaster Stack Exchange and just for clarification added a tag for Opencart on this post

Comment: Cross-site post on Webmasters: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114179/how-to-add-force-https-to-htaccess-file-rewriterule-with-route-1

Comment: (FWIW, I don't think this question is particularly off-topic on this site - it _is_ about programming _and_ development. However, it is probably more suited to the Webmasters stack.)